# Node.js: forEach arrow statement drama

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get the below snippet to work, but for some reason, I can't get the script to recognize the "element" part of the "attributes.States.element" line.
Is it because there is a "." in the line?

If I am to make the first line of the forEach section "console.log(element);", it works perfectly.

If I use it as laid out below it fails not recognizing "element".
This snippet is being used in **Node.js 8.10** in an Alexa skill.

** Edited to include entire Handler statement in the Alexa code.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;

        const attributes = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes() || {};

        const speakOutput = 'Hello World!';

        attributes.States = { 
        };

        const stateNames = ['Alabama', 'New York'];

        stateNames.forEach(element => {
            attributes.States.element = {
                'found' : 'no',
                'history' : 'no'
            };
        });
        attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes(attributes);
        await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes();

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Comment: what is `attributes` ? i don't see anything defined as `attributes`

Comment: Post complete snippet or try to console the first and second for each element.

Comment: this is wht you looking for `attributes.States[element]` ??

Comment: are you trying to add States to each array element? Can you add the expected output in your question?

Comment: @Code Maniac Maybe he has attributes declared as a variable above the stateNames declaration

Comment: @sagar.acharya may be or maybe not, but should post the relevant data, so that people can help him with exact reason for problem, instead of guessing, it's always better to post the relevant data with question IMO

Comment: @codeManiac Agreed! :D

Comment: Thanks for the responses all.  In the Alexa skills kit, "attributes" is defined to utilize the Attributes manager.  I'm changing the code above to include it, thanks for pointing that out.  The goal is to add each state to a List in a dynamoDb utilizing the Alexa Skills Kit attributes manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to refer to a property named 'Alabama' or 'New York' in `attributes.States` then you should use `attributes.States[element]`.

The difference here is that the `element` is being used as a value and not as a property name.

Comment: Thank you Ale, that was indeed the answer.  The "." in the line was the issue, being that it shouldn't be there at all!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "HelloWorldIntent"
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;

    const attributes =
      (await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes()) || {};

    const speakOutput = "Hello World!";
    // Add the following condition to avoid changing the data if something is returned from the getPersistentAttributes()
    if (!attributes.States) {
      attributes.States = {};
    }
    const stateNames = ["Alabama", "New York"];

    stateNames.forEach(element => {
      attributes.States[element] = {
        found: "no",
        history: "no"
      };
    });
    attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes(attributes);
    await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes();

    return (
      handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
        .getResponse()
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: That was the fix, thanks Sagar!  I figured it was something simple that I was missing.